# Can .NET detect failed CAC authentications?

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis, smartcard, cac

I have a .NET application using web forms that uses CAC login to authenticate users.

Currently the application stores a history of successful CAC logins, but we would like to also include history of any unsuccessful CAC authentications (ie: if user goes to site, but enters wrong PIN during CAC prompt).

Is it possible to detect unsuccessful CAC authentications in .NET, and if so, how can this be accomplished?